# Can I pass a model variable to an external .js

Tags: javascript, java, thymeleaf

I have two coordinates that I'm passing to an html file via model variables. In the html itself (it's using thymeleaf, by the way), I can access them like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
  /*<![CDATA[*/
  var mapInitLat = [[${mapInitLat}]];
  var mapInitLng = [[${mapInitLng}]];
  /*]]>*/
</script>
```

In the same html, I'm including an external .js file:

```
<script src="/js/map/myTools.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to make mapInitLat and mapInitLng visible inside myTools.js?

Comment: It's certainly _possible_. The current best practice seems to be to create an endpoint called something like `/config.json` that is entirely generated (e.g., with `@ResponseBody` in Spring) and fill in your config values there.

Comment: Well thanks for the alternative, but my question was specifically if I can pass the existing model variables to the .js file. If it's not possible, I'll probably follow your suggestion.